# How can I get rails to send javascript errors to the log, not alert?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rjs

JavaScript errors to an alert box injure my soul. Is there a way to send it to `console.log()` instead of `alert()`?

Comment: for rjs, try out http://maintainable.com/software/firebug\_rjs\_errors (somehow the link does not work when embedded)

Answer (score 4):

You could override window.alert:

```
var oldAlert = window.alert; // reference to the original window.alert

window.alert = function(message) { 
  if (window.console && console.log) { 
    console.log(message); 
  } else { 
    oldAlert(message); // if console.log doesn't exist call window alert
  } 
}
```

Comment: That would work but that's quite brutal imho. But still good solution so +1

Comment: Solution for now! But I really want to explore that plugin from below--just in case I need to use alert in the app (which I never do, I consider popups in nearly any form profanity)

Comment: if you use the :confirm parameter in links, it will also use alert

Comment: In JS confirm and alert are different, though they are both agitating.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `console.log("error message goes here")`

Comment: i think he meant the alerts, that rjs generates ;)

Comment: Yes, Rails does a lot of stuff on its own, I suppose I should add the tag rjs

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Javascript error.  Since JavaScript is interpreted by the client, you would need to display the error messages client-side.  The only real way to log errors in the server log file is if the error is happening on the server side before the Javascript is interpreted by the client.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but console.log is a javascript function for browser debugging tools (webkit's inspector, firebug, and IE8's new thing) that I'm trying to use instead of Rails default alert().

Answer (score 0):

You could try turning off RJS debugging of in your environment.rb file:

`config.action_view.debug_rjs = false`

This should turn off the alerts altogether. Another option would be overriding `ActionView::Helpers::GeneratorMethods#to_s`:

```
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module GeneratorMethods
      def to_s #:nodoc:
        returning javascript = @lines * $/ do
          if ActionView::Base.debug_rjs
            source = javascript.dup
            javascript.replace "try {\n#{source}\n} catch (e) "
            javascript << "{ console.log('RJS error:\\n\\n' + e.toString()); console.log('#{source.gsub('\\','\0\0').gsub(/\r\n|\n|\r/, "\\n").gsub(/["']/) { |m| "\\#{m}" }}'); throw e }"
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I admit I'm out of my depth as far as overriding the method goes, and I don't know if it's a recommended practice. I haven't needed to do anything like this in my projects.

My personal preference would be to skip RJS and go with unobtrusive jQuery.

Comment: Not sure how prototype is more obtrusive ... but anyway, I'm going to give prototype/scriptaculous a shot.  Most the stuff I do is xhr heavy, so I'd like to "keep it in the family" instead of messing around with JS separately. I'm a mootools man myself and can already see myself wanting to use it.

Comment: I'm sure you can go unobtrusive with prototype but that would mean giving up using a lot of the helpers AFAIK. I like writing and controlling my JS so it works for me.